# If condition (multiple cond)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Need help with my if conditions.

```
if(userId && !targetId){
// query logic for userid and no targetid
} 
else if (!userId && targetId){
// query logic for targeted and no user id
}
```

Now how do I write the "else" part? another query logic for when both userid  and target id are present.

Comment: Something like `else if(userId && targetId)` will check if both values are truthy

Answer (score 3):

You may simply tag on another if else:

```
if (userId && !targetId) {
   // query logic for userid and no targetid
} 
else if (!userId && targetId) {
    // query logic for targeted and no user id
}
else if (userId && targetId) {
    // query logic for both true
}
else {
    // this defaults to both being false, the other three
    // conditions already being handled above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do

```
else
{
 if(userId && targetId){ }
}
```